# Como sobrescrever uma imagem sem absolute? HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Meu objetivo é inserir uma imagem de fundo que possa ser escrita por cima com `<h2>, <p>` e etc por cima dela, mas sem o uso do position: absolute pois isso interfere os sub-menus da página aparecendo textos e etc por cima deles quando exibidos !!

Comment: Cara coloca o que vc já tem de código ai, HTML e CSS, da forma como vc peguntou sem o código não da para te dar uma resposta precisa... Talvez o problema nem seja o position, mas a forma como vc mentou o menu. Então quando puder edite sua pergunta e inclua os códigos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui segue um exemplo, utilizando `background-size: cover`, ele redefine o tamanho para ser suportado dentro do container que você deseja, no caso toda essa `<section>`, mesmo tendo que esticar a imagem ou cortar um pouco dela:

```css
.main-section{
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/ODmMf1p.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-section h2{
  font-size: 30px;
}
.main-section p{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-section">
  <h2>Título Aqui</h2>
  <p>Texto Aqui</p>
<section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem, mas poderia tentar da seguinte forma.
Aplica o conteúdo dentro de <header> e via css aplica.

```
header {
  background-image:url('add caminho imagem');
  width: 100%;
}
```